# Checking if in "Critical" section using JNI on Android

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

In the link (https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jni/), it states that:

"Ensure the code does not make any JNI calls or block for any reason between calls to GetXXXCritical() and ReleaseXXXCritical()."

When I do so, I get the following error in my logs.

W/dalvikvm(19853): JNI WARNING: threadid=1 using JNI after critical get (NewByteArray)

Is there a way to determine whether I am actually in between "Criticial" calls as stated above?  I checked through a lot of JNI documentation and I can't seem to find a function that will indicate so.

Comment: A critical region would typically be quite small, so within the same function you should know whether you're in a critical region or not. If you call other functions of your's within the critical region you could e.g. pass a `bool` parameter to them that is `true` if you're in a critical region (it could be a default parameter that gets the value `false` if you don't pass anything).

Comment: Thanks Michael.  I am actually trying to work around a library issue.  I am using a library that is apparently calling back into my code while in a critical section.  I am not sure that the library is actually maintained anymore so asking someone to fix the issue in the library is not an option :( I am not sure why JNI doesn't provide a function like "IsInCriticalSection" or something similar.

Comment: If you can't make any JNI calls when you are in a critical region, how could you call such a function to check if you were?